Problema con wxWidgets, CMake y MSYS2: "libwx_mswu-3.2.a" no encontrada durante la compilación con Ninja
Estoy por empezar a aprender a interfaces graficas en C++ y estoy algo frustrado al intentar compilar un proyecto de C++ utilizando wxWidgets, CMake y MSYS2 en Windows. A pesar de que CMake configura correctamente el proyecto y encuentra todas las librerías necesarias, al intentar compilar con Ninja, obtengo el siguiente error:
ninja: error: '/mingw64/lib/libwx_mswu-3.2.a', needed by 'bin/wxwidget-template.exe', missing and no known rule to make it

Detalles del entorno:

Sistema Operativo: Windows
Instalación de MSYS2: D:/msys64
Compilador: MinGW-w64 (g++ y gcc)
wxWidgets: 3.2.5 (compilado en modo monolítico)
CMake: 3.26.0
Generador: Ninja

Utilizo principalmente VS Code para el proyecto pero también he intentado por medio de la consola msys2 y obtengo el mismo error.
Para configurar el src de wxWidget use:
../configure --enable-optimise --enable-stl --enable-unicode --disable-shared --enable-monolithic
make install

Comando utilizado para configurar CMake en el proyecto de wxWidgets:
cmake -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=D:/msys64/mingw64/bin/g++.exe -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=D:/msys64/mingw64 -DwxWidgets_ROOT_DIR=D:/msys64/mingw64 -DwxWidgets_LIB_DIR=D:/msys64/mingw64/lib -DwxWidgets_CONFIGURATION=msw-unicode-static-3.2 -DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE:BOOL=ON -G "Ninja" ../../..

Salida de la configuración de CMake:
-- wxWidgets found: 3.2.5
-- wxWidgets include dirs: /mingw64/lib/wx/include/msw-unicode-static-3.2;/mingw64/include/wx-3.2
-- wxWidgets libraries: -L/mingw64/lib;;;-Wl,--subsystem,windows;-mwindows;/mingw64/lib/libwx_mswu-3.2.a;-limm32;-lwxtiff-3.2;-lwxjpeg-3.2;-lwxpng-3.2;-lwxregexu-3.2;-lwxscintilla-3.2;-lwxexpat-3.2;-lz;-lz;-lrpcrt4;-loleaut32;-lole32;-luuid;-luxtheme;-lwinspool;-lwinmm;-lshell32;-lshlwapi;-lcomctl32;-lcomdlg32;-ladvapi32;-lversion;-lws2_32;-lgdi32;-loleacc;-lwinhttp
-- Configuring done (9.7s)
-- Generating done (0.1s)

Error al ejecutar "ninja":
ninja: error: '/mingw64/lib/libwx_mswu-3.2.a', needed by 'bin/wxwidget-template.exe', missing and no known rule to make it

Archivo "CMakeLists.txt" (es un popurri de todos los tutoriales que he visto):
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)

project(wxwidget-template LANGUAGES CXX)

# allow me build with useful warnings
if (DEFINED DEVEL AND NOT DEVEL EQUAL 0)
  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Werror") 
  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall") 
  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wextra") 
  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Weffc++") 
  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -pedantic") 
endif()

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib)
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib)
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin)

set(wxWidgets_ROOT_DIR "D:/msys64/mingw64")
set(wxWidgets_LIB_DIR "D:/msys64/mingw64/lib")
set(wxWidgets_LIBRARIES "D:/msys64/mingw64/lib/libwx_mswu-3.2.a")
set(wxWidgets_INCLUDE_DIRS "D:/msys64/mingw64/include/wx-3.2;D:/msys64/mingw64/include;D:/msys64/mingw64/lib/wx/include/msw-unicode-static-3.2")
set(wxWidgets_CONFIGURATION "msw-unicode-static-3.2")

# Añadir directorios de enlace e inclusión
include_directories(${wxWidgets_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${wxWidgets_LIB_DIR})

find_package(wxWidgets REQUIRED COMPONENTS monolithic)
#find_package(wxWidgets REQUIRED)

if (wxWidgets_FOUND)
  message(STATUS "wxWidgets found: ${wxWidgets_VERSION_STRING}")
  message(STATUS "wxWidgets include dirs: ${wxWidgets_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
  message(STATUS "wxWidgets libraries: ${wxWidgets_LIBRARIES}")
  include(${wxWidgets_USE_FILE})
else()
  message(FATAL_ERROR "wxWidgets not found!")
endif()

add_subdirectory("src")

Archivo "src/CMakeLists.txt":
include_directories(.)
include("${wxWidgets_USE_FILE}")

file(GLOB sources *.cpp)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} WIN32 ${sources}) 

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${wxWidgets_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${wxWidgets_LIBRARIES})

install(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME} RUNTIME DESTINATION bin)

Variables de entorno dentro MSYS2:
WXWIN=/mingw64
MINGW_PREFIX=/mingw64
MINGW_PACKAGE_PREFIX=mingw-w64-x86_64
MSYSTEM=MINGW64
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/mingw64/lib/pkgconfig:/mingw64/share/pkgconfig
LDFLAGS=-L/mingw64/lib
CXXFLAGS=-I/mingw64/include -I/mingw64/include/wx-3.2

Ya comprobé que efectivamente el archivo "libwx_mswu-3.2.a" existe en el directorio "D:/msys64/mingw64/lib".
Tengo casi una semana investigando en internet y con ChatGPT y no logro dar con el origen del problema. No se si talvez sea por la forma en que se escriben las rutas porque son diferentes el estilo Unix y Windows pero no tengo ni idea de como resolverlo. Agradezco cualquier ayuda o sugerencia que puedan darme. Gracias de antemano.

Solo tienes el problema con Ninja? Por cierto, no es recomendable poner librerías externas junto con las que vienen con el compilador. Tampoco lo es usar rutas absolutas. Siempre es mejor dedicar una carpeta dentro de tu proyecto para los include y librerías.

@Mateo intente con el generador Unix Makefiles y el comando make y me da el mismo error que no encuentra el archivo "libwx-mswu-3.2.a". Y sobre lo demás, dices que debo copiar los archivos de cabecera y la librería directamente dentro de la carpeta de cada proyecto?

Si, es recomendable poner los .h y librerías dentro del proyecto. Si tienes algún repositorio podría intentar reproducir el problema

Si, subi todos los archivos incluyendo los de VS Code por si hay algún problema en ellos. https://github.com/ClynnJ/wxwidget-template
